Creating an Alluvial plot with ggplot
I am trying to create an Alluvial Plot in R for longitudinal gene expression data. The code works fine and I kind of get what I need.
My problem is though, that I would like that the color code for the Foldchanges (Up, Down, Unchanged) stays the same throughout the different Timepoints (Time1 to 5). Now as it is, the color to the genes sticks for the Time1. I probably think it should be something with scale color manual argument, but I don't know how it is affected with geom_alluvium (fill). Sorry I'm new to R
Maybe someone of you knows the answer?
Code with example data is provided below
#Code with sample data
genes <- paste0("Gene", 1:10)
time_points <- paste0("Time", 1:5)
regulation_states <- c("Up", "Down", "Unchanged")

# Create example data
df <- expand.grid(Gene = genes, TimePoint = time_points) %>%
   mutate(Regulation = sample(regulation_states, size = n(), replace = TRUE))

# Pivot data to have one column per time point's regulation state
df_wide <- df %>%
 pivot_wider(names_from = TimePoint, values_from = Regulation, names_prefix = "Regulation_") %>%
 # Ensure that time point columns are correctly ordered
 mutate(across(starts_with("Regulation_"), factor, levels = regulation_states))


# Define a color palette for regulation states
color_palette <- c("Up" = "#1f77b4", "Down" = "#ff7f0e", "Unchanged" = "grey")

# Plotting
ggplot(df_wide, aes(axis1 = Gene, axis2 = Regulation_Time1, axis3 = Regulation_Time2, axis4 =       Regulation_Time3, 
                axis5=Regulation_Time4,axis6 = Regulation_Time5 ,y = 1)) +
geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Regulation_Time1), width = 0.3) +
geom_stratum(width = 0.3, color = "grey") +
geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), size = 3) +
scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Gene", paste0("Time", 1:5)), expand = c(0.15, 0.05)) +
scale_fill_manual(values = color_palette) +
labs(title = "Alluvial Plot of Gene Regulation Transitions",
   x = "Gene and Time Points",
   y = "Count",
   fill = "Regulation State") +
theme_minimal() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))



Perhaps use the long format df, and start with ggplot(df, aes(x = TimePoint, stratum = Regulation, alluvium = Gene, fill = Regulation)) + geom_flow() +    geom_stratum().
